# Who is in response for memory management with malloc()

Tags: c, memory-management

Maybe it is the matter of taste but let's say you are developing some library and there is custom data type in it:

```
struct My_custom_type { ... };
```

So the question is: how would it be more properly to allocate memory for this data type and initialize it in client code?

```
My_custom_type *foo;
foo = malloc( sizeof( My_custom_type ) );
init_my_custom_type( foo );
```

versus

```
My_custom_type *foo = init_my_custom_type();
```

In last example `init_my_custom_type()` is in charge for memory allocation.

In other words, who is in the response ( generally ) for memory allocation, library developer or the client who uses that library?

Comment: It is a style preference.  But writing functions that return pointers to dynamically allocated memory that needs to be released isn't very good style.  You need a Big Comment to remind the client programmer that this is a hard requirement.  The closer the malloc and free call in the source code, the lower the odds the program will have a memory leak.

Comment: @HansPassant every function that returns pointer makes me more suspicious ) thanks for "closer the malloc and free call"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either can be responsible, it's up to you. This is one of decisions you have to make when designing an API.

Allocating in the library is slighty more convenient for the client, but potentially less efficient. It always requires a heap allocation, and unless you make the API more complicated to let the client override the allocation functions (say, by accepting function pointers), it also interacts badly with the custom allocators many larger or resource-constrained projects use. Furthermore, *when* to deallocate is still the responsibility of the client (only they know when they're done), it just happens by calling a function of the library rather than talking to the allocator directly.

Having the client supply memory is less convenient, and more error-prone (e.g., more places where the wrong amount of memory could be allocated), but can be more efficient. The client can allocate memory on the stack and pass that to `init_*`:

```
My_custom_type foo;
init_my_custom_type(&foo);
```

The most important thing is that you are **consistent**. If the library allocates it, the library needs to free it. Conversely, if the client allocates it, the client needs to free it. This is not only more comprehensible, it also avoids errors when the client and the library disagree on what allocator to use (which is easy to do accidentally when linking dynamically on some platforms).

Comment: It seems that user-based memory control has more pros over the api-based. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems both variants are used. But if you are going to use second one (i.e. allocate memory inside library), it's worth to give to the user the option to provide own allocators like `set_allocators(malloc, free);`